# Is there any law regarding the milk of a sacrifiicial animal?

Tags: food, sacrifice, udhiyyah

As far as I know it is valid to sacrifice a female animal on eid (ewe or cow), who could be lactating. Is there any restriction on using the milk of that animal?

Answer (score 0):

There are laws regarding the prohibited parts of sacrificial animals. So any other part is considered halal.